# File upload URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to upload a canvas image to my server using AJAX, the AJAX is working fine, however when I give the server the URL it converts it and adds backslash in at every folder in the URL, and I cant see how. I need it to stop adding these backslashes into the string.

```
if(isset($_POST['saveCanvas']) && $_POST['saveCanvas'] == "1"){
    $img = $_POST['canvasURL'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64','',$img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+',$img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = "https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images" . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    $return = [];
    $return['success'] = 1;
    $return['message'] = 'Image Uploaded!  ' . $file;

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

This is what I want the output to look like `https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images` and this is the current output `https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/my-plugin\/images5f7d97548917d.png`

Comment: What “output” are you talking about? You are returning a JSON data structure here, and inside that, by default, slashes will be escaped. But that will be reversed, when you _decode_ the JSON again, so this sounds as if you were not doing that correctly, when you output the data somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, this happens because you are JSON encoding your return array. Did you try to just returning `$file` upon success?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current issue I would suggest you do this on your php.

```
if(isset($_POST['saveCanvas']) && $_POST['saveCanvas'] == "1"){
    $img = $_POST['canvasURL'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64','',$img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+',$img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = "https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images" . uniqid() . '.png';
    echo file_put_contents($file, $data) ? $file : 0;

}
```

This will check if the file has been uploaded and return a file name or the integer 0.

When the response reaches your ajax, the ajax will check the response.

if its 0, it will be counted as false so you can do.

```
if(response){
//success code
}else{
//fail code
}
```

For example

```
alert(response ? 'Image Uploaded! '+ response : 'Failed to upload');
```